Is 你觉得市场上的几款都不太满意 ungrammatical?
This is from the HSK6 Standard Course textbook (下册, chapter 21, page 4; photo of original; OCR via Yandex):

消费者加入设计队伍，是未来商店着重推荐的服务，譬如，你想买衣服，可是你觉得市场上的几款都不太满意，那就参与设计吧。你登录到虚拟设计室，进入设计过程，对颜色、外观等设计内容进行投票，这样设计出来的衣服保管你满意。

I feel the part I highlighted in bold is ungrammatical because of sentences like this:

你觉得我不满意。  (You think/feel I'm not satisfied.)

so I'd expect

A + 觉得 + B + 不满意。

to mean "A thinks B is unsatisfied" rather than "A is unsatisfied with B".  If I were writing the sentence, I'd write:

你对市场上的几款都不太满意。

Maybe I'm missing something though (e.g., sometimes language can be used flexibly), so...
Question: Is 你觉得市场上的几款都不太满意 ungrammatical?

You cannot arbitrarily leave out 可是, "but", and the sentence must be read as following on from the whole of the previous parts.

Both sentences "你觉得市场上的几款都不太满意" and "你对市场上的几款都不太满意" are correct and mean the same.
"你觉得市场上的几款都不太满意" - A thinks (feels) that A (himself or herself) is unsatisfied with B". The Chinese sentence omitted the subject of the clause. 你觉得(你对)市场上的几款都不太满意.
你对市场上的几款都不太满意 - A is unsatisfied with B.
Another example:
我觉得不想吃饭 - I feel that I do not want to eat.

Your feeling is correct.
The right sentence would be 你对市场上的几款都不太满意 or 你觉得市场上的几款都不太令人满意。


Is 你觉得市场上的几款都不太满意 ungrammatical?

either 觉得 should be replaced by 对 --> "你对市场上的几款都不太满意" (it would make it a word choice error)
or the sentence omitted a subject.
Define the subject would make the sentence more clear
Example:
你觉得市场上的几款都不太[讓人]满意
你觉得市场上的几款都不太满[你]意
你觉得市场上的几款都不太满[消費者]意


你觉得市场上的几款都不太满意

I think the verb "觉得" shall be followed with a phrase (不太满意) that describes it rather than a noun phrase (市场上的几款):

你對市场上的几款都覺得"不太满意" - You feel unsatisfied with all the models on the market.


你觉得"我不满意",... (You think/feel I'm not satisfied.)


Here, "我不满意" is the phrase that describes 觉得(feel).


你对市场上的几款都(覺得/感到)不太满意。

This is a good substitution for the original sentence. However, it would be a more complete sentence with the words in parentheses not omitted.
